# How to calculate the minimum and maximum number of matches between two sequences?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have two sequences of the same length $n=3$: $\{A,B,C\}$ and $\{A,A,B\}$. When I compare them, there is 1 match since both have an "$A$" in the first position. Generating all 6 permutated versions of each list, I can see that I will get at most 2 matches, and at least 0 matches. Since generating and comparing all permutations soon becomes impracticable ($!n^2$) for longer sequences, is there another method to calculate the minimum and maximum number of matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum, as it has been mentioned already by @Browning, if you look at the intersection of the multisets, you may simply place what is common to both at the front of the sequence in the same way for both.

E.g. $\{A,A,A,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,E\}$ and $\{A,A,B,C,C,C,C,D,D,D,D\}$

The arrangements $AABCCCDDABE$ for the left and $AABCCCDDCDD$ for the right share eight matching positions.  It is plain to see that this is the maximum possible.  (A simple proof might involve temporarily treating each copy of $A$ as distinct, instead as $A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, C_1, C_2, C_3, \dots$ and explaining that the maximum number of matches of this related problem corresponds to the maximum of the original problem)

For the minimum number of matchings, consider the pigeon-hole principle.

Consider the most commonly appearing letter, say $A$, and count the number of occurrences in each multiset.  Say it occurs $a_1$ number of times in the first multiset and $a_2$ number of times in the second multiset.  Let $k=a_1+a_2$ be the total number of times it occurs.

If $\frac{k}{n}> 1$, then you *must* have a match somewhere (seen immediately by pigeonhole principle, the pigeons being the occurrences of $A$ and the holes being the positions in the sequence).

In fact, since each hole has a maximum capacity of two, you can see that the number of matches of locations of $A$ will be equal to $\max\{k-n,0\}$.  Furthermore, if some letter satisfies the condition that $\frac{k}{n}>1$ then that implies that no other letter may occur enough times to be forced to match as well.

For example, the sets $\{A,A,B,C,C\}$ and $\{A,B,B,C,C\}$ can be permuted in such a way as to have no matches.  For example, $AABCC$ for the left and $CCABB$ for the right.  On the other hand, the sets $\{D,D,D,D,E\}$ and $\{D,D,D,E,F\}$ will be forced to have at least two matches, for example with $DDDDE$ and $EFDDD$ for the right.

---

Final answer:  Let the multisets be $\{a_1\cdot A, a_2\cdot B,\dots, a_k\cdot K\}$ and $\{b_1\cdot A, b_2\cdot B,\dots,b_k\cdot K\}$ such that $a_1+b_1+\dots+k_1=a_2+b_2+\dots+k_2=n$ with the multisets written in multiplicity notation (*$a_1$ is the number of occurrences of $A$ in the first set, $b_1$ is the number of occurrences of $A$ in the second set, et cetera*)

The maximum number of matches between the two multisets will be:

$$\#\text{of maximum matches} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \min\{a_i,b_i\}$$

The minimum number of matches between the two multisets will be:

$$\#\text{of minimum matches} = \max\{a_i+b_i-n,0\}_{i}$$

Comment: Nice solution.  In your “Final Answer” paragraph, you meant to say: Let the multisets be $\{a_1\cdot A, a_2\cdot B,\dots, a_k\cdot K\}$ and $\{b_1\cdot A, b_2\cdot B,\dots,b_k\cdot K\}$ such that $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k=b_1+b_2+\dots+b_k=n$ with the multisets written in multiplicity notation (*$a_1$ is the number of occurrences of $A$ in the first set, $a_2$ is the number of occurrences of $B$ in the first set, et cetera*)

Answer (score 0):

For the maximum, look at the cardinality of the intersection of the multisets.